# Bootstrap images in columns overlapping

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have been trying to get 3 images to be responsive using bootstrap columns. They seem to be responsive, but the problem is that the images overlap except for the last column which remains being normal.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-3">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/roy-creates-categories-02.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/roy-creates-categories-02.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/roy-creates-categories-02.png">
        </div>
  </div>
```

[image]
I would like all 3 columns to like the one all the way on the right.

I've tried adding class "img-responsive" & "img-fluid" and neither have worked.

I'm using bootstrap 4.0.

Comment: There shouldn't be any overlap given your above code; you should have three `col-2` images evenly spaced with even `col-3` margins either side. Can you please ensure you have provided a  [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Comment: Why are  you offsetting the first column? That will change how it interacts with the other two cols.

Comment: Offsetting because I want the 3 images to be centered on the page

Comment: @NathanielFlick even if I remove the offset it still does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The images are overflowing their container. The image on the right is full height but it is overflowing its container. Using the bootstrap '.col-2' means that you are limiting the column widths based on the window width. You could use `background` css rules instead of img elements to ensure containment or coverage of images or you could just use `.col-auto` instead of `.col-2` with `.justify-content-center` provided you have appropriately sized images.

All three examples are in the snippet.

```css
.row {
 min-height: 150px;
 }

.col-auto {
  background-color: green;
}

.col-sm-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/100");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg-image.bg-image--cover {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-3">
    <div class="bg-image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="bg-image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="bg-image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-3">
    <div class="bg-image bg-image--cover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="bg-image bg-image--cover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="bg-image bg-image--cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```